# AES: how to generate key from password for every algorithm size

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Is it possible to write a single method that generates valid keys from a password for AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256?

I'm thinking in something like this:

```
    SecretKeyFactory f;
    try {
        f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new Exception("Key derivation algorithm not available.", e);
    }
    KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
    SecretKey s;
    try {
        s = f.generateSecret(ks);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new Exception("Key generation failed.", e);
    }
    Key k = new SecretKeySpec(s.getEncoded(),"AES");
```

I was using a similar approach to generate salted keys for AES-256. However, now I have to generate keys just from a password (with no salt and no iterations), and I need them to work for AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256. My question is, does this code return keys compatible with every AES-XXX size, or should I write different code for each size?

Also, is there a better (in terms of security or simplicity) way of generating a key from a password?

UPDATE: Finally I made some tests and it turns out that this constructor:

```
KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
```

Always throws an `InvalidKeySpecException` on this block:

```
try {
    s = f.generateSecret(ks);
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    throw new Exception("Key generation failed.", e);
}
```

So I'm stuck with the other constructor, that needs a salt as a parameter:

```
KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), "somepredefinedsalt".getBytes(), numIters, keySizeInBits);
```

As I don't have a salt, I've thought of hardcoding a predefined one. Now I don't know which option is more secure, coding a predefined salt and using PBKDF2 or using a truncated hash.

Comment: A salted, lengthened hash is pretty strong.  You could just truncate the result to whatever length you need after generating 256 bits.

Comment: @bdares If I use a portion of a 256 bit hash to get a key of 128 or 192 bits, then two different passwords could generate the same truncated key.

Comment: that, alas, is so very true.  Unfortunately, an infinite number of passwords could generate the same key with hashing functions.  You just have to take solace in the fact that it's really bloody difficult to intentionally do it.

Comment: @bdares Yes, it is very difficult to find two different messages with the same hash, but considering only a part of the hash, then the collision probability could be much higher, I think. It will depend on the hash function, but in general I don't have a good feeling about doing it.

Comment: Each bit is very hard to predict, so predicting and colliding just the top 128 bits, or the bottom 128 bits, or every other bit, is just as hard (per bit).  That's why it's a desirable property of cryptographic hashes.  If you consider that they're effectively random from the attacker's point of view, a subset of a random set of digits is still random, and is just as good as another, smaller, differently generated random set of numbers.

Comment: @bdares "_A salted, lengthened hash is pretty strong._" Strong in term of what? How does a salt make the key stronger? How are you going to transmit the salt?

Comment: @MisterSmith "_then two different passwords could generate the same truncated key_" It's ridiculously unlikely. If you care about such odds, why not assume your adversary can find the 128 bits key by randomly trying 128 bits numbers? ;)

Comment: @curiousguy A secure hash function, such as SHA-256, effectively takes 2^256 time to brute.  (That may be closer to 2^254 now, I heard of an attack that reduces the complexity by 2 bits.)  However, if you prepare a rainbow table (theoretically possible), you can break hashed passwords in constant time.  So you construct a unique salt for each password, and store it in plaintext.  No need to transmit it at all.

Comment: @curiousguy a salt makes a key stronger by adding entropy to the password its derived from. Afterwards, the salt can be transmitted in the open.

Comment: @bdares If the hash is "predefined", it is a constant, so it adds strictly no entropy.

Comment: @Ivo If the salt is transmitted in clear, thus potentially known to someone listening to the connexions, how could it protect anything?

Comment: @curiousguy You should take a look at the Birthday Problem.  The idea is that if you start hashing a bunch of random strings, you'll find collisions with users' passwords, and then you'll know their passwords.  If each user effectively has a different hash function because they have a different salt, then it becomes brute force again.

Comment: @bdares What is the size of the output of the hash function?

Comment: @curious 256 bit, but we're talking about how secure could be truncating it to 128 or 192 bits.

Comment: @bdares Do you have around 1e19 active accounts?

Comment: @curiousguy You're just trying to be obnoxious.  Educate yourself on what a hash is used for, and the ways that people attack it.  Then you will be able to ask the right questions.  Until you realize you don't understand how this stuff works and decide to learn, nothing I can say will convince you.

Comment: @bdares Obviously your understanding of hashing is, to say it very kindly, not sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, **do not do that.** A user selected password typically has **very poor entropy**.

**If** the "password" is not user selected, but instead produced by a **cryptographically strong** RNG, use the password, or a hash of the password. In this case, you do not need PBKDF2.

PBKDF2 is really the last resort solution.

Please also read [Lessons learned and misconceptions regarding encryption and cryptology](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology)

Comment: I have to derive a key from a user selected password of any length. I've two options: truncate a 256bit hash, or apply PBKDF2 with a predefined salt (the user doesn't type the salt, so it must be a constant in the application code). I've a better feeling with the second option.

Comment: I have to include the salt because there's no other way to create a new `PBEKeyspec` instance with a given key length.

Comment: What the heck? PBKDF2 uses a hash in it's operation. I don't know why it's a 'last resort' when simple hashing isn't :S you may want to read up on its definition.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted. What you're calling a password there, I'd just call a key.

Comment: @Ivo I meant that using a password to make a key is a last resort solution, as passwords usually have poor entropy, and using one as a key exposes the password to off-line attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate a 256bit length key to the size needed. The key should be random, or generated using a secure method such as PBKDF2. If in doubt, hash for more length / even-randomness-distribution before truncating.

You can also see that [PBEKeySpec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html) allows you to optionally specify the key length.

Comment: Please read my answer below to understand what my doubts are now.

Comment: Please describe how PBKDF2 is "secure". Do you consider it "secure" because it is slow?

Comment: @curiousguy, I use that in relation to the many custom non-secure ways programmers come up with for deriving a key from a password.

Comment: @Ivo PBKDF2 is no magic, it is mathematical function. If you deduce a cryptographic key from a low entropy password, then your key will have low entropy. There is no way around that.